# why using a modulo-2 arithmetic in crc?

Tags: crc

I learned an error detection technique called crc. crc calculations are done in modulo-2 arithmetic without carries in addition or borrows in subtraction. I wonder the reason why crc takes modulo-2 arithmetic rather than regular binary arithmetic. Is it easier to be implemented in digital circuit?

Comment: Because if you only care about the last bit, there's no point in keeping track of the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe better late than never for an answer. A CRC treats the data as a string of 1 bit coefficients of a polynomial, since the coefficients are numbers modulo 2. From a math perspective, for an n bit CRC, the data polynomial is multiplied by x^n, effectively adding n 0 bit coefficients to the data, then dividing that data + zeroes by a n+1 bit CRC polynomial, resulting in a n bit remainder, which is the CRC. If "encoding" the data with a CRC, the remainder is "subtracted" from the data + zeroes, but for single bit coefficients, adding and subtracting are both xor, so the CRC is just appended to the data, replacing the zeroes that were appended to the data to generate the CRC.

The reason for no carries or borrows across coefficients is because it's polynomial math.

Although not done for CRC, Reed Solomon codes are somewhat similar, but the polynomial coefficients may be numbers modulo some prime number other than 2, such as 929, and for prime numbers other than 2, it's important to keep track of when addition or subtraction modulo a prime number other than 2 is used.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reed%E2%80%93Solomon_error_correction

Comment: great answer, it really helped me get insight into why rather than other answers that state how.